# Data Access And Entity Classes inside MVC

Tags: architecture, mvc, application-design

Sorry for this question seems naive. I am new to MVC model (I know I am a bit late to join the club), and I have a question regarding MVC with PHP. I think the implementation language doesn't really matter but I intended to specify it in order to make it clear that I use web applications.

I am planning to use Entity classes (like Car, User, etc..) but these are more like Business logic classes. So I need to use persistence data layer such as Data Access classes (Car DAL that includes actual SQL statements).

Now I am not sure how and where these classes will fit in MVC. I think they are part of the model, but I don't know how this will be done.

I am thinking of using AngularJS with PHP and MySql. Trying to create my first truly MVC project, but not sure how all will fit together. Please feel free to ignore the implementation specifics if you feel they don't belong to the question.

Comment: Did you checked this out?http://stackoverflow.com/q/5863870/5934037 . There's a nice introduction to MVC and It's based on php

Comment: My question in this link might have some answers to that, as I've had similar q over the years http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/336649/mvc-and-mvvm-lack-the-grabbing-data-model-using-entity-boundary-controller-in